# Add new field in existing built in Application of iPhone

Tags: iphone

Hope you all are fine and are in your best of moods.

I herewith one doubt to ask you, kindly help me by giving its solution.

I need to add one custom field in existing built in Contact Application of iPhone.

I mean i need to allow user to set different icon or Logo for different contact.
so i need to add one field namely icon or Logo in existing application.

But I don't know how to do this, weather it is possible or not or is there any alternate solution for that or not???

kindly post your Answers.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You have the source code/own the application or are you talking about trying to alter somebody else's application to which you only have the binary distribution?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot add fields to the built in Address Book datastore. You could perhaps achieve your goals by one of two solutions:

- make a copy of the data and add your data to that. You will hit sync problems
- Use some property (perhaps ABPropertyID) of the AB information to key a local database referencing your icons.

I'm assuming what you actually want to do is add an icon to the address book app - there is certainly no way to do that.